# Hover and active states in less

Tags: css, less

Can you add an active state on the same line as a hover state in [less] or does it have to be nested on line separate lines?

example:

**standard less**

```
nav {
    color:@black;
    display:block;
    &:hover {color:@primary-color;}
    &:active {color:@primary-color;}    
}
```

**somehow to do this**

```
nav {
    color:@black;
    display:block;
    &:hover, &:active {color:@primary-color;}    
}
```

I've tried: [&:hover, &:active;] I've tried: [&:hover; &:active;] but it's doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Actually yes you can, and the second variant you provided is correct as long as you define the `@primary-color` variable:

```
@primary-color: #f00;
@black: #000;

nav {
  color: @black;
  display:block;
  &:hover, &:active {color:@primary-color;}    
}
```

will produce:

```
nav {
  color: #000000;
  display: block;
}
nav:hover,
nav:active {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

Comment: yes I did that in my mixins.less file. thanks Juicy. It's late and i'm making mistakes with my code.

Answer (score 1):

It's late and my stupidity tells me to go to bed.

**Juicy Scripter** get's the win, I get the lose for back coding mistakes.

But yes,

```
nav {
  color: @black;
  display:block;
  &:hover, &:active {color:@primary-color;}    
}
```

Is the answer.

Comment: @JuicyScripter got his acceptance tick checked as a sign of your appreciation, and he got my +1. So I don't think there is a real need for reposting the answer. But glad you got it to work. Good night ^_^